# PhantomJs unable to process jasmine spyOnProperty

Tags: angular, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I am spying on 2 of my properties using `spyOnProperty` and they are working good in `intellij` console for karma testing and debug mode in browser but when I run them using phantomjs they give me error mentioned below.

Code I am using to test

```
const div = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.xxxx'));
div.triggerEventHandler('mouseover', null);
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(component.tooltip.isOpen()).toBeFalsy();

// now spying on to see if its behavior changes
spyOnProperty(div.nativeElement, 'clientWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(1400);
spyOnProperty(div.nativeElement, 'scrollWidth', 'get').and.returnValue(2400);
```

#### Error

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) EllipsisOverflowComponent should show tooltip on mouse over of the element FAILED
    Error: clientWidth is not declared configurable in http://localhost:9877node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js (line 4410)
    http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/main.bundle.js:8593:22
    invoke@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:12949:31
    onInvoke@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:136846:45
    invoke@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:12948:40
    run@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:12699:49
    http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:136543:37
    http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:183754:31
    invoke@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:12949:31
    onInvoke@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:136080:45
    onInvoke@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:136843:47
    invoke@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:12948:40
    run@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:12699:49
    http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:183749:28
    http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/vendor.bundle.js:136069:46
    invokeTask@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:12982:36
    runTask@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:12749:57
    invoke@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:13044:45
    timer@http://localhost:9877/_karma_webpack_/polyfills.bundle.js:14070:34
```

Comment: it only happens for PhantomJs browser. runs well for chrome and other

Comment: You might need to add some polyfills for phantomjs

Comment: I think you are on the right track with it not working with read only properties, let us know

Comment: yap! I actually created a bug for protractor guys and also they confirmed that `spyOnProperty` is not working on for read only properties only for `phanotmjs`  driver